# Application Icon in Windows Market

Tags: windows-phone-7, submission

I added appIcon to my apps and it is 62x62 like the sample one, but when I go into the market everything is bigger. Should it be in a higher resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Windows Phone Iconography]

Refer [CREATING WINDOWS PHONE 7 APPLICATION 
AND MARKETPLACE ICONS.](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-in/gg317447.aspx)